# Features from a feature class do not display when zooming beyond 1:3000 scale

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase

I am running ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 on a Windows 10 computer.

Points from a feature class in a file geodatabase are not displaying beyond 1:3000 scale on a layer with no visibility range limits set. At wider scale they cannot be selected from the map, but can be selected from the attribute table and their locations are highlighted as normal on the map. Problem is not tied to anything in the project as it persists when a copy of the feature class is added to a new empty map lacking even a basemap.

Based on similar threads I have tried the following with no success:

- Delete and recalculate the spatial index of the feature class
- Clear ArcGIS Pro's display cache
- Check/Repair Geometry
- Open on a different computer

Exporting the feature class to a shapefile resolves the problem but strips it of all the domain and subtype architecture and truncates the attribute field names that are too long.

Any suggestions or am I stuck rebuilding in a new geodatabase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does sound like some sort of corrupted featureclass. A trick I have used is to create a new featureclass and import the field definitions during the create featureclass, and you then use the Append tool to append the source rows (you corrupted dataset). Try that?

Comment: This did it, just have to futz with the subtypes as they didn't get transferred over and it will be back to 100%